# Brightness method shows "Out of memory" exception

Tags: c#-4.0, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

To change brightness of an image in c#.net 4 i have used the following method.

```
 public void SetBrightness(int brightness)
    {
        imageHandler.RestorePrevious();
        if (brightness < -255) brightness = -255;
        if (brightness > 255) brightness = 255;
        ColorMatrix cMatrix = new ColorMatrix(CurrentColorMatrix.Array);
        cMatrix.Matrix40 = cMatrix.Matrix41 = cMatrix.Matrix42 = brightness / 255.0F;
        imageHandler.ProcessBitmap(cMatrix);
    } 

      internal void ProcessBitmap(ColorMatrix colorMatrix)
          {
            Bitmap bmap = new Bitmap(_currentBitmap.Width, _currentBitmap.Height)

            ImageAttributes imgAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
            imgAttributes.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmap);
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            g.DrawImage(_currentBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, _currentBitmap.Width,   
            _currentBitmap.Height), 0, 0, _currentBitmap.Width, 
            _currentBitmap.Height,  GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgAttributes);
            _currentBitmap = (Bitmap)bmap.Clone();


        }
```

If brightness is changed several times then "Out of memory" exception is shown. I have tried to use "Using block" but went in vein.

Any ideas?

please see the link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/227016/Image-Processing-using-Matrices-in-Csharp 
and suggest if any types of optimization is possible in the methods (Rotation, brightness, crop and undo).

Comment: You are probably forgetting to call Dispose() on the Bitmap objects.  They take a lot of unmanaged memory, the garbage collector won't keep you out of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the projects from CodeProject and I have fixed the memory leak. You need to dispose the Graphics object and the `_currentBitmap` image before you override it. Also, you need to stop using `.Clone`.

If you replace the contents of the `ProcessBitmap` function with this code, the memory leak is gone:

```
internal void ProcessBitmap(ColorMatrix colorMatrix)
{
  Bitmap bmap = new Bitmap(_currentBitmap.Width, _currentBitmap.Height);
  ImageAttributes imgAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
  imgAttributes.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix);
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmap))
  {
      g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
      g.DrawImage(_currentBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, _currentBitmap.Width, _currentBitmap.Height), 0, 0, _currentBitmap.Width, _currentBitmap.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgAttributes);
  }
  _currentBitmap.Dispose();
  _currentBitmap = bmap;
}
```

Also, here are some tips for further optimization:

- Stop using `.Clone()`. I have seen the code, and it uses `.Clone()` everywhere. Don't clone objects unless really necessary. In image processing, you need a lot of memory to store large image files. You need to make as much processing as you can in-place.
- You can pass `Bitmap` objects [by reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) between methods. You can improve performance and reduce the memory cost that way.
- Always use `using` blocks when working with `Graphics` objects.
- Call `.Dispose()` on the `Bitmap` objects when you're sure you don't need them anymore

Comment: Also, you need to learn how to [accept answers (link)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). If you find an answer that works for you, click the tick box next to it.